# Populate ComboBox1 with a horizontal/transposed row from excel sheet1

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I am trying to populate a ComboBox1 from a row in my excel sheet.  Everything I'm finding online is from 2006 and doesn't work when I try it. Wondering if this is even possible? 

ComboBox name = ComboBox1

Data = Sheet1(A1:Z1)

Please assist if possible. Thank you!

Comment: I think is not possible to set the source of a combobox ActiveX linked to a row. It must be a "vertical range". I mean a column.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub populateCombo()

  count = 1

  While (count <= 26)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, count).Copy (ActiveSheet.Cells(count, 27))
    count = count + 1
  Wend
  ComboBox1.List = Range("AA1:AA26").Value
  Range("AA1:AA26").Delete

End Sub
```